# Tetris recursive does not work as i predicted

Tags: c, recursion, tetris

First of all, apologize my awful english. I hope you can understand my question. :)
below function is tetris game's recommend system.
It search every possible x, y positions and get a best position which gives highest score(max).
It is based on data structure - Tree.
I call this function with NULL pointer at first.
so the first depth's prev == NULL.
recommend X, Y, R / Field[HEIGHT][WIDTH] is global variable.
checktomove function returns 1 when the block moving is possible.
if you need more information about this code, I can upload the whole code.

Goal:
At level 0: call level 1 recursively
At level 1: call level 2 recursively
At level 2: search the best score and return the score
At level 1: search the best score returned from level2 and return the score
At level 0: serach the best score returned from level1, and if the score is highest, record the position at that time on global variable. It will be used at drawing recommended blocks.

ERROR: I used tile2 for debugging, and if it works correct, then the tile2 must be '3'.
But when I run the program, tile 2 is '2' and I guess this means the loop does not go into
if(curr->level==0) recommend x, y, r...
But what makes it stranger is, x, y, r changes (almost) all the time.
How could this happen?

```
int recommend(Leaf_pointer prev){
    int max=0, tmp;
    int acc_score;
    int rotate, x, y, i, j;
    char originField[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    rec=0, swip=0, tile2='2';
    Leaf_pointer curr = (Leaf_pointer)malloc(sizeof(Leaf));
    if(prev==NULL){
        curr->level = 0;
        acc_score = 0;
        for(i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
            for(j=0; j<WIDTH; j++){
                originField[i][j] = field[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        curr->level = prev->level + 1;
        acc_score = prev->accumulatedScore;
        for(i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
            for(j=0; j<WIDTH; j++){
                originField[i][j] = prev->recField[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    curr->curBlockID = nextBlock[curr->level];
    if(curr->curBlockID==4)
        rotate=3;
    else if(curr->curBlockID==0 || curr->curBlockID==5 || curr->curBlockID==6)
        rotate=2;
    else    
        rotate=0;
    for(rotate=0; rotate<4; rotate++){
        for(x=-1; x<WIDTH; x++){
            for(i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++){
                for(j=0; j<WIDTH; j++){
                    curr->recField[i][j] = field[i][j];
                }
            }
            if(x==WIDTH)
                break;
            y=0;
            while(CheckToMove(originField, curr->curBlockID, rotate, ++y, x));
            y--;
            curr->accumulatedScore = acc_score + AddBlockToField(curr->recField, curr->curBlockID, rotate, y, x);
            curr->accumulatedScore += DeleteLine(curr->recField);
            if(curr->level<VISIBLE_BLOCKS-1)    
                curr->accumulatedScore=recommend(curr);
            if(max < curr->accumulatedScore){
                max = curr->accumulatedScore;
                if(curr->level==0){
                    recommendY = y;
                    recommendX = x;
                    recommendR = rotate;
                    tile2='3';
                }
                rec=1;
            }
        }
    }
    free(curr);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: "if you need more information about this code, I can upload the whole code." No. A [mre] should be your goal.

Comment: What is the purpose of `y` passed to `CheckToMove()`? The call `while(CheckToMove(originField, curr->curBlockID, rotate, ++y, x));` means it is never `0`. BTW the English is less of a concern than the dire formatting.

Comment: Strangely, although the location `y` can never be `0` in `CheckToMove`, the `x` can be `-1` in this function. Perhaps you have off-by-one problems in the code.

Comment: The poor formatting disguises the fact that `if(x==WIDTH) break;` can never happen, because it is inside the loop `for(x=-1; x<WIDTH; x++)`. And if it were moved outside the loop, it would always to true.

Comment: sorry for my formatting. I will refine it and question again

Comment: I have formatted the code for you.